# Calculate leaderboard rankings based on redis stored sets

Tags: javascript, redis

So i am trying to calculate rankings calculate leaderboard rankings based on redis stored sets.

I am using this https://redis.com/solutions/use-cases/leaderboards/ functionality, however with stored set can not calculate tie breakers.

I am looking for dense rankings.

For an example.

```
const scoring = [
  { entryId: 4, score: 2196000 },
  { entryId: 5, score: 2196000 },
  {  entryId: 7, score: 2196000 },
  { entryId: 9, score: 2196000 },
  { entryId: 6, score: 2211000 },
  { entryId: 11, score: 2211000 },
  { entryId: 15, score: 2211500 }
]

const rankings = scoring.map(({ entryId, score}, index) => {
    const currentScore = score
    const sameScore = scoring.find(({ score }) => score === currentScore)
    const sameRank = sameScore ? scoring.findIndex(({entryId}) => entryId === sameScore.entryId) + 1 : 0
    const rank = sameRank ?? index + 1
    return {entryId, rank}
})

console.log(rankings, 'results')
```

So i am looking something like this

1. entryId: 4
2. entryId: 5
3. entryId: 7
4. entryId: 9
5. entryId: 6
6. entryId: 11
7. entryId: 15

So if you have idea.

1. Which data structure to use instead of redis stored sets?
2. Potentially keep redis stored sets, and improve algo (more efficient) without **.find()** & **.findIndex()**

Here is test playground

```js
const scoring = [
  { entryId: 4, score: 2196000 },
  { entryId: 5, score: 2196000 },
  {  entryId: 7, score: 2196000 },
  { entryId: 9, score: 2196000 },
  { entryId: 6, score: 2211000 },
  { entryId: 11, score: 2211000 },
  { entryId: 15, score: 2211500 }
]

const rankings = scoring.map(({ entryId, score}, index) => {
    const currentScore = score
    const sameScore = scoring.find(({ score }) => score === currentScore)
    const sameRank = sameScore ? scoring.findIndex(({entryId}) => entryId === sameScore.entryId) + 1 : 0
    const rank = sameRank ?? index + 1
    return {entryId, rank}
})

console.log(rankings, 'result')
```

Comment: Did you check the Top-k? 
https://redis.io/commands/?group=topk

Comment: Well i will keep storted sets, and try to optimeze algo